# Powershell replace csv object

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to make expiring certificates report, but have issue with replacing Certificate Expiration Date OID inside the csv exported from "certutil".
ForEach-Object command don't recognize the column and replaces whole csv, though I can filter Template using Where-Object.

```
$currdate = Get-Date
$date = (Get-Date).AddYears(2)
$template = "RDP|IIS"
$path = "C:\Temp\"
    if(!(test-path $path))
{
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
}
certutil -view  -restrict Disposition=20 -out "Request.CommonName,NotAfter,CertificateTemplate" csv | Out-File $path\ExpiredCerts.csv 
Import-Csv $path\ExpiredCerts.csv | ForEach-Object {$_.'Certificate Template' -replace "^\d.* ",""} 
Import-Csv $path\ExpiredCerts.csv |Where-Object {$date -gt $_.'Certificate Expiration Date' -and $currdate -lt $_.'Certificate Expiration Date' -and $_.'Certificate Template' -match $template} | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header | Out-File $path\ExpiredCerts.htm
```

---

**CSV**

```
"Request Common Name","Certificate Expiration Date","Certificate Template"
"*.piltover1.com","11/06/2022 13:08","1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.9809061.13872499.9847428.7216726.9936658.242.11024705.6775621 IIS"
"*.piltover2.com","11/06/2022 13:08","1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.9809061.13872499.9847428.7216726.9936658.242.11024705.6775621 IIS"
"*.piltover3.com","11/06/2022 13:08","1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.9809061.13872499.9847428.7216726.9936658.242.11024705.6775621 IIS"
```

**Final Result**

```
$currdate = Get-Date
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(30)
$template = "RDP|IIS"
$path = "C:\Temp\"
    if(!(test-path $path))
{
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
}
certutil -view  -restrict Disposition=20 -out "Request.CommonName,NotAfter,CertificateTemplate" csv | Out-File $path\ExpiredCerts.csv
$data = Import-csv $path\ExpiredCerts.csv
foreach ($item in $data) {
    $item.'Certificate Template' = ($item.'Certificate Template' -split ' ')[-1]
}
$data | Where-Object {$date -gt $_.'Certificate Expiration Date' -and $currdate -lt $_.'Certificate Expiration Date' -and $_.'Certificate Template' -match $template} |
        ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header | Out-File ExpiredCerts.htm
```

Comment: Could you add an example of how the exported file looks, as plain text (just a few lines for testing)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon
"Request Common Name","Certificate Expiration Date","Certificate Template"
"*.piltover.com","11/06/2022 13:08","1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.9809061.13872499.9847428.7216726.9936658.242.11024705.6775621 IIS"
"*.piltover.com","11/06/2022 13:08","1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.9809061.13872499.9847428.7216726.9936658.242.11024705.6775621 IIS"
"*.piltover.com","11/06/2022 13:08","1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.9809061.13872499.9847428.7216726.9936658.242.11024705.6775621 IIS"

Comment: Please edit your question and put the wanted extra info in there as formatted text. In a comment it becomes unreadable

Comment: I've added your CSV to the question but for future reference, please always add all the needed information there and not in the comment section. If you're not sure how to format it, you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70422745/edit) your question and see how the formatting was done.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thank you, noted for the future.

Comment: Please validate that how I added the CSV is how it literally looks from your side.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon i've already made some changes, thank you.

Comment: You never save or capture the output for the ForEach-Object anywhere and the line below that imports a completely different file called `Ex.csv`... Also, why trying to change the values in that column anyway? Using `$template = "(RDP|IIS)$"` to use in the regex `-match` should do it..

Comment: @Theo regex -match does it's job, but the requirement is to have no OIDs in output file. Yes, I forgot to change Ex.csv actually there should be the same file. I've already changed code in question, thank you for note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this to remove the OIDs from column 'Certificate Template' and without the need for writing that data to file and re-importing it, create a HTML file from it.

This assumes you already have the raw data from certutil in a CSV file:

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path (Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath 'ExpiredCerts.csv')
# remove OIDs in column 'Certificate Template'
foreach ($item in $data) {
    $item.'Certificate Template' = ($item.'Certificate Template' -split ' ')[-1]
}
# filter the data you need based on expiration date and template
$data | Where-Object {$date -gt (Get-Date $_.'Certificate Expiration Date') -and 
                      $currdate -lt (Get-Date $_.'Certificate Expiration Date') -and 
                      $_.'Certificate Template' -match $template} | 
        ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header | Set-Content (Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath 'ExpiredCerts.htm')
```

P.S. I'm using `Set-Content` in favor if `Out-File` because we don't know what version of PowerShell you are using. In PS version 7.x, the default encoding for Out-File is `utf8NoBOM`, while in PS version 5.1 the default file encoding is `unicode` (= `UTF16-LE`) which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you for help, it does it's job! I've made some changes to fit my code. Added final result to question.